# Generate Static HTML Pages using Java

Tags: java, html, jsp, java-8, java-7

I have a unique problem to solve. I need to dynamically create HTML based reports using a standard template. The contents of the report are created by a Java program so it makes sense to create a new class which uses JSP* to make a static HTML output file.

Here is the gist:

```
MyObject me = new MyObject();
me.process();

MyJSP jsp = new MyJSP(me);
File output = jsp.renderFrom("templateFile.jsp");
```

And `output` is a static, self contained HTML file which I can open in IE/Firefox and see the report.

What pattern/framework should I follow to allow me to best accomplish this?

Some notes: This is actually not a webapp. I am creating HTML based reports, but this won't be used as a webapp. I would also rather not use `String.format(".. giant template string .. ", args)` as this is very clumsy. I would much rather have a template file like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>First JSP</title></head>
<body>
  <%
    double num = Math.random();
    if (num > 0.95) {
  %>
      <h2>You'll have a luck day!</h2><p>(<%= num %>)</p>
  <%
    } else {
  %>
      <h2>Well, life goes on ... </h2><p>(<%= num %>)</p>
  <%
    }
  %>
  <a href="<%= request.getRequestURI() %>"><h3>Try Again</h3></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Where the "dynamic" aspects of the template can use `MyObject` properties, etc.

Lastly, I plan to use Java 7 for this due to some issues I am having with Java 8. If there is some better way to do this in Java 8, let me know...

*After some negative comments against JSP, perhaps JSP is not the right option. Some other library is fine too, as long as it works with Java.

Comment: It's a bad idea to write Java inside your JSP. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/139010

Comment: JSP is for writing *dynamic* HTML files. A *static* HTML file has no dynamic content.

Comment: Can you recommend an alternative than, some other library besides JSP. In the end, I still need to develop static HTML reports... rather not use `String.format(...)`

Comment: Okay I took out the JSP specific part of the question. Would be great if the down votes got undone so the question doesn't get filtered out.

Comment: I'm not sure ripping jsp out of a servlet container will be that easy, but then I never tried it so I could be wrong. [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) is probably easier.

Answer (score 2):

Use a template engine for this!
I would recommend Freemarker, Velocity or StringTemplate. Just google it. Any of these engines will cover your needs.